# CoverFlow with Buttons instead of Images

Tags: iphone, ios, coverflow

I am using this great project for Cover Flow (OpenFlow) for the iPhone.

https://github.com/thefaj/OpenFlow/

However, this only supports images. When I modified the code to include a button for example, it is not getting the touch event, so therefore I am not able to press the button.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can have coverflow and also make it usable as a UIView (with buttons and interactable UIkit stuff) and not just an UIImage?

Thanks

Comment: I want to do the same with OpenFlow were you able to achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago. I used iCarousel for that (MIT License!)

You can find the source [on BinPress.com](http://www.binpress.com/app/icarousel/614)

iCarousel is easy to implement an can be "filled" with any UIView Control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bring the button to the front, `[view bringSubviewTpFront:button];`

Comment: No cigar :( Seems like the touch events are used for dragging/navigating the coverflow.